# tooltipster get value from span ID

Tags: jquery, tooltipster

I need to retrieve the value of the tag 'id' in a span when using the Tooltipster jQuery script. Below is the used code. When doing an alert on the variable 'id' to check, I get the result 'UNDEFINED'.

Can anyone please advise how to get '1928_34' as a result for the variable 'id'? Thx!

## HTML

```
<div class='content'>
    <span id='1928_34" title="Please wait..." >Click here</span>
</div>
```

## Tooltipster jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".content span" ).tooltipster({
        contentAsHTML: true,
        interactive: true,
        trigger: 'click',
        arrow: false,
        minWidth: 900,
        minHeight: 900,
        maxWidth: 900,
        plugins: ['tooltipster.sideTip', 'laa.scrollableTip'],

        functionBefore: function(instance, helper) {
            var $origin = $(helper.origin);
            var id = $(this).attr('id');                    
            alert(id); 
            if ($origin.data('loaded') !== true) {
                $.get('get_tooltip.php?id='+id, function(data) {
                    instance.content(data);
                    $origin.data('loaded', true);
                });
            }
        }
    });             
});
```

Comment: Your code seems to work fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/hy1esed3/8/. Shot in the dark, but you might be getting issues because your HTML uses an ID that starts with ' and ends with ".

Comment: Thx Daniel D for your response!  
The single quote / double quote where a copy-paste mistake from my side when making this post.  
  
I thought it might be a conflict in the name of the class ('content') somewhere else in the code. So I changed the class to 'tooltipcontent', but the 'id' is still not passed by the code '$(this).attr('id')'.  
  
Do you have any other suggestions?